# Visual Studio Git Not Updating and Commit Issues

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am new to git and have been having some trouble with committing from Visual Studio. Just recently, Visual Studio started to not update my changes. Then when I tried to commit it gave me multiple errors. The changes disappeared though. The errors from the output.

1. Git: Failed to execute git
2. git fetch
   fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
   remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
3. fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'

This just started happening after many commits. I looked all over the forums but have had no success. Everything in the `git config --list` is set accordingly. It is a private repository though. Would that effect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all,

set your remote repository using,

```
git remote add upstream repsitory_url
```

it will solve your 2 and 3 error. it seems you dont have any remote repository to push thats why. so copy your repo name and add it into your project using above command.

for eg:

```
git remove add upstream github.io/my_prj/proj.git
```

Comment: Can you change the remote upstream url? Its set to a old repository. I tried and it gave me fatal.

Comment: you can... you can add multiple remote . it will be differentiated by origin/upstream. so if you setted origin you can add upstream also...

Answer (score 0):

I just re-opened my same directory and it somehow fixed everything. I guess when it re-opened Visual Studio it went one directory to far up and would not recognize it. `~/code/src/code2/src2` for some reason it opened src and not the 'code2' directory.